# popup window layout design left blank space

Tags: android, android-layout

My popup window design left blank space on top of the window. i try different layout options but space persist.i don't understand how to eliminate this.i am using Custom popup   Please help.
[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFF" 
       android:text="Input a Value"/> 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/severity_rating"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
  <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/popup_et"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="100dp" 
        android:inputType="number" />
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ok"/>
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonCancel"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cancel"/>
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);`

Answer (score 0):

Setting height to fill_parent to the first linear layout doesn't help ?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: And if you set
android:layout_height="wrap_content" to other items in the main layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

and your imageview give as src

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/severity_rating"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use android:layout_weight="" for your linearlayout objects and arrange their appearance in window. Use especially for the item which will occupy more space.
[Popup Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iipu.png)
for this view, I use

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/popborder_record"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCHLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/md_blue_grey_200"
    android:text="@string/checklistsetup"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvCheckList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="8" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="@string/lblSoru"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="@string/lblPuan"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_weight="9"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="10"
        android:inputType="number"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnAdd"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCHSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/strSave" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCLClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/strOFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you use weight on each element with will also cause spaces. So use for object for important.